# how repeat a string in language C

Tags: c

how I do to repeat a string?
something like "hello world" * 3 
the output "hello world hello world hello world"

Comment: You need to tell us how you want to use it, if you have a real habit of repeating strings, you could store a structure with the string and a repeat count, and repeat the string when you need it. I'm guessing you want to repeat the string in memory? If you only need to repeat the string when doing output, just write it three times..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your source code, without much processing, probably the easiest way is with:

```
#define HI "hello world"
char str[] = HI " " HI " " HI;
```

This will declare a string of the requested value:

```
"hello world hello world hello world"
```

If you want *code* that will do it, you can use something like:

```
char *repeatStr (char *str, size_t count) {
    if (count == 0) return NULL;
    char *ret = malloc (strlen (str) * count + count);
    if (ret == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy (ret, str);
    while (--count > 0) {
        strcat (ret, " ");
        strcat (ret, str);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now keep in mind this can be made more efficient - multiple `strcat` operations are ripe for optimisation to avoid processing the data over and over <sup>(a)</sup>. But this should be a good enough start.

You're also responsible for freeing the memory returned by this function.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Such as with:

```
// Like strcat but returns location of the null terminator
//   so that the next myStrCat is more efficient.

char *myStrCat (char *s, char *a) {
    while (*s != '\0') s++;
    while (*a != '\0') *s++ = *a++;
    *s = '\0';
    return s;
}

char *repeatStr (char *str, size_t count) {
    if (count == 0) return NULL;
    char *ret = malloc (strlen (str) * count + count);
    if (ret == NULL) return NULL;
    *ret = '\0';
    char *tmp = myStrCat (ret, str);
    while (--count > 0) {
        tmp = myStrCat (tmp, " ");
        tmp = myStrCat (tmp, str);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use sprintf.

```
char s[20] = "Hello";
char s2[20];
sprintf(s2,"%s%s%s",s,s,s);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made this function based on earlier answers in this post.
I share it here because some of previous examples has been thrown me segfaults

```
const char* str_repeat(char* str, size_t times)
{
    if (times < 1) return NULL;
    char *ret = malloc(sizeof(str) * times + 1);
    if (ret == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(ret, &str);
    while (--times > 0) {
        strcat(ret, &str);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/5sNylW

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
     char k[100];
     gets(k);
     int lk=strlen(k);
     int times;
     scanf("%d",&times);
     int tl= times*lk;
     int i,x=0;
        for(i=lk-1;i<tl;i++)
        {
        k[i+1]=k[x];
        x++;
        }
    for(i=0;i<tl;i++)
    {
    printf("%c",k[i]);
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try write own function. It will be work with single-length string also (i. e. duplication a single char). It use the function "strcat()" from the "string.h", so do not forget include this header.

```
char *
str_repeat(char str[], unsigned int times)
{
    if (times < 1)
        return NULL;

    char *result;
    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    result = malloc(sizeof(char) * str_len + 1);

    while (times--) {
        strcat(result, str);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, if you need only duplication of a string for print it, try macro

```
#define PRINT_STR_REPEAT(str, times) \
{ \
    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) \
        printf("%s", str); \
    puts(""); \
}
```

Results

```
PRINT_STR_REPEAT("-", 10); // ----------
puts(str_repeat("-", 10)); // ----------

PRINT_STR_REPEAT("$", 2); // $$
puts(str_repeat("$", 2)); // $$

PRINT_STR_REPEAT("*\t*", 10); // *   **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  *
puts(str_repeat("*\t*", 10));  // *   **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  **  *

PRINT_STR_REPEAT("*_*", 10); // *_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_*
puts(str_repeat("*_*", 10)); // *_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_**_*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to repeat a string in C, N times.

That is have a string "abc" 
and I want a string of length 7 that is comprised of this string repeated.

N = 7;
result: "abcabca"

```
 while(Index != N){

    repeatedString[Index] = oldString[Index%strlen(oldString)];
    Index++;
 }
```

Where repeated String would be "abcabca" at the end, and oldString is "abc".