# How to add string elements successively in C?

Tags: c, string, function, repeat

I want to add string elements successively, for example `st[]="morty"`, and I want to repeat its elements for example seven times. It should be `st[]="mortymo"`. I wrote a function which is at below. (The length function is `strlen`).

```
    void repeat(char* st,int n){
         int i,k=0,l=length(st);
         char* ptr;
         ptr=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
         for (i=0;i<n;i++){
              *(ptr+i)=*(st+k);
              k++;
              if(k==l)k=0;
         }
    }
```

Comment: You allocate memory and store its address in `ptr` but then you discard `ptr` at the end of the function. This not only leaks memory, but discards the result of your operation. Shouldn't you return `ptr`?

Comment: And you'll want to nul-terminate your allocated string, too.

Comment: What does it do now vs. what it should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how repeat a string in language C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770940/how-repeat-a-string-in-language-c)

Comment: @Zusaetlich "...for example st[]="morty", and I want to repeat its elements for example seven times. It should be st[]="mortymo"." - Which elements are repeated 7 times?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

The program below repeats characters from the original string.
Comments in the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 char* repeat(const char* st, size_t n){
         // use `const` to note that pointer `st` will not be modified
         // for purity you may want to use type `size_t` since returning type of strlen is `size_t` 

         size_t i, k=0;
         size_t l = strlen(st);

         // do not use (char *) cast
         char* ptr = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char)); // allocate enough room for characters + NULL

         for (i=0; i< n; i++)
         {
              ptr[i] = st[k]; // use index for readability
              k++;

            if (k == l)
                k=0;
         }

         ptr[i] = 0; // terminate the string


    return ptr;
 }

int main( )
{
    char *str = "12345";

    str = repeat(str, 15);

    printf("%s\n",str);

    free (str); // free the allocated memory inside the repeat function

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
123451234512345
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `repeat` function, you allocated `ptr` to hold the repeated string, but you didn't return or assign it to `st`. You can modify your `repeat` function as follows:

```
    char* repeat(char* st,int n){
         int i,k=0,l=strlen(st);
         char* ptr;
         ptr=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
         for (i=0;i<n;i++){
              *(ptr+i)=*(st+k);
              k++;
              if(k==l)k=0;
         }
        *(ptr+n) = '\0';
        return ptr;
    }

    /* some code*/
    char *st = "morty";
    st = repeat(st, 7);
```

Such that you are storing the result of the repeated string in `st` after.

Comment: You never added the trailing null.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the assignment correctly then you need a function like that one shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * repeat( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    char *p = NULL;

    size_t len = strlen( s );

    if ( len == 0 ) n = 0;

    p = ( char * )malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( p )
    {
        size_t i = 0;

        for ( size_t j = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            p[i] = s[j];
            if ( ++j == len ) j = 0;
        }

        p[i] = '\0';
    }


    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Hi, Zusaetlich.";

    char *p = repeat( s, 2 * strlen( s ) );

    puts( p );

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hi, Zusaetlich.Hi, Zusaetlich.
```

Pay attention to that the function is designed such a way that if the original string is empty then the resulted string is also empty because there is nothing to repeat.

As for your function then it has at least a memory leak because the memory allocated in the function is not freed.

Also as the original string is not changed then the corresponding parameter should be qualified with the `const` specifier.  And the second parameter should have type `size_t` because at least the function `strlen` has the return type `size_t`.

So the function should be declared as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong in his version and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't intend to modify the contents of `st`, go ahead and declare it as `const`. Since you intend to allocate a new string in your function, you should return it to the caller.

```
char *repeat(const char* st,int n){
```

`k` is unnecessary for your problem. Call the standard functions.

```
     int i,l=strlen(st);
     char* ptr;
```

Don't cast the result of `malloc`, as this can mask a fatal error in C. `sizeof(char)` is always 1. Check the result of the `malloc` call for success.

```
     ptr=malloc(n+1);
     if (ptr == NULL) return NULL;

     for (i=0;i<n;i++){
```

Access arrays idiomatically with `[]`. Note that `k` increments whenever `i` does, but you are applying a modulo operation of `k`. However, C has a modulo operator, which you can use directly on `i`.

```
          ptr[i]=st[i%l];
     }
```

Make sure the new string is `NUL` terminated. Your function is declared to return a result, but your implementation fails to do so.

```
     ptr[n] = '\0';
     return ptr;
}
```

C has many functions you can call to do the copying for you rather than the byte by byte loop you have written. There is simplicity in your implementation, but below is an alternative, that also includes additional error checking that is lacking in your solution.

(Some may balk at the use of `sprintf`, but it is being used correctly.)

```
char *
repeat (const char *st, int n) {
    int l = st ? strlen(st) : 0;
    char *ret = (st && n > 0 ? malloc(n+1) : 0), *p = ret;
    while (ret && n > 0) {
        p += sprintf(p, "%.*s", (l < n ? l : n), st);
        n -= l;
    }
    return ret ? ret : "(nil)";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBRa4MwFIXf/RUHR0u0WixlL9rWP7IXF7MaiFeJ6cYY/nZ31VrYGMw83HBPvnPPJTK@Sjk8aZLmViqcOlfqZl9dvB@S0a@/Navpytogq8Ii9KxqVeEgZEOdwyx2LoImBwrw5YHP2BicwUTOxRpFonMBUiTZBMw@qxxD/ILtFoQLEsbrwphGCtodJj6IELZMMTtbPyptFMToXVxL7Hha7Di35a3dm2gj@Jt92PkRhMGJ6Zz3SnnRiNcKsoeLEJ9h5r6fKs@/WRov5Cl8QdoEfub1Aw/26kITxHujyyX6HuhvuhfitPmXhF835D65PxyDe9rfYPI/8pgVrybXcs8ruUMygv3wDQ)

Comment: It is unclear to me what is wrong with the answer from the POV of the OPs request, but I have tightened up the error checking.